# Having duplicate rows on a primary key and unique constraints in postgres

Tags: sql, postgresql

I have 4 tables ranging from 10 million rows to 25 million. I first created the tables with one table having serial_no as a primary key and the rest have a combination of two columns as a unique constraint.

Then I inserted large csv files to them which was successful. Then I added more records using an upsert technique which also went well. But then when I was randomly selecting specific serial numbers I noticed that some of them have duplicate rows. to make sure I then grouped by serial_no and filtered by count(*) > 1 and sure enough, many records are duplicated even with the constraint in place. What could be the problem here?

I read a previous post where it says an older version of Postgres (namely 9.2 and before) had a bug but it was supposedly fixed. I'm using version 10. Also, all tables have duplicate records on their respective unique constraints.

Comment: You have to show your `CREATE TABLE` statements and an example of data **you think** is violating these constraints.

Comment: I found the problem. I did not create those tables manually but rather used pgAdmin4 interface and naively chose to inherit from another table thinking it will just copy it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After looking around I found my answer. Sharing for others who might face a similar problem.

So the problem was that I was using inheritance to create my tables. I never had to deal with inheritance before so when I was creating tables using pgAdmin4 interface I was choosing to inherit from other tables thinking it was just a shortcut to create a similar table with similar columns. Well, it was not and it turned out primary keys are not enforced among inherited tables.

I ended up deleting all tables and starting from scratch without using inheritance.